# No se puede acceder a una instancia en Openstack

Tags: cloud

Ok, estoy aprendiendo sobre openstack, y acabo de correr una instancia de test con cirros, el problema es que cuando quiero acceder a la misma con el comando ssh -i

> MyKey.pem cirros@192.168.1.116

me sale el error

> connect to host 192.168.1.116 port 22: No route to host